# Web API - Protect GET from anchor tag using CORS

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors, asp.net-web-api2

i have created a GET web api method that is going to be referred to from an anchor tag outside of my application (one of our vendors).

i was thinking this would not work out of the box because of CORS but I guess this only happens when making calls via javascript / ajax ???

what would be a good solution to ensure this method is only called by certain domains (including our site)?

Comment: Maybe you could add a logic that would only allow some IP addresses to reach it.

Comment: ok so is my thinking correct CORS is only for ajax calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer this [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) it should give you the information you are looking

Checkout the section **Set the Allowed Origins**

Comment: is this for javascript clients making requests? i'm not at my computer right now to test.

Comment: this is for your question on "ensure this method is only called by certain domains" + in general how to enable CORS on api in general

Comment: I found this on internet, hope this helps http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: ok thanks to the both of you. this should get me moving in the right directdionl

Comment: javascript sample
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Feature detection for CORS
if ('withCredentials' in req) {
    req.open('GET', 'http://api.foo.com/products', true);
    // Just like regular ol' XHR
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (req.readyState === 4) {
            if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400) {
                // JSON.parse(req.responseText) etc.
            } else {
                // Handle error case
            }
        }
    };
    req.send();
}

Answer (score 0):

```
  [EnableCors(origins: "http://example.com, http://example1.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
   public class Controller1 : ApiController
   {
    ...
   }
```

Put this attribute above your controller class
 Replace http://example.com and http://example1.com  with domains you want to allow